# Personal .config file does not work in C# Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, config, project

What can be the reason that the personal `.config` file does not work in C# Visual Studio project?

I had the `Business.config` in a project and I added the `Business.Debug.Yaroslav.config`. Then I unloaded and reloaded the project. And now I expect the properties specified in the `Business.Debug.Yaroslav.config` to override the properties in all other `Business.*.config` files. But it does not happen.

[image]

While the same steps above worked for another `.config` file in the same project. The `App.Base.config`.

[image]

The properties specified in the `App.Debug.Yaroslav.config` really override the properties in other `App.*.config` files.

Also I picked the configuration as the `Debug.Yaroslav`.

[image]

How can I make the `Business.*.config` to use a personal `.config` file depending on the current solution configuration (in my case I want to use the `Business.Debug.Yaroslav.config` when the configuration is `Debug.Yaroslav`)?

I am using the Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SET THAT PROPERTY at the app initialization:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile = "";
```

this must work if you access config properties by config manager

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But maybe you know why the `.config` for the `Business` and the `App` display so differently? I would expect all my custom `.config` files to go below the `Business` node just as it is for the `App`.

Comment: I can't really imagine why you have many different config files without watching them, but I can say that every .config file should have a predefined format, take a look to this tutorial:

https://blog.submain.com/app-config-basics-best-practices/

Comment: What do you mean by watching in this context?